# Ajax pager of views does not work when using in quicktabs

Tags: views, ajax, blocks

I have 2 views that are using pagers since they display lists of articles. Each view is within a tab of a quicktab. The views are set to use AJAX.

Right now, I am able to move between the pages of the first view which is inside the first tab. The problem is when I move to the second tab and I try to use the pager to move through the pages. No matter what page I choose (in the second tab) the page redirects me to the first tab and the second page.

Also, I´ve set both pagers ID to a different number but the problem has remained the same.

This is where it points the second page of the second tab: localhost/drupal/live-healthier?**page=1&js=true**

To summarize, how can I use 2 views inside quicktabs with ajax pagers?

Thank you for your help !

Comment: Thanks for the replay. I forgot to write that in the question. I´ve already set the two pagers ID to different number (first view pager ID: 0 and second view pager ID: 1) but still the same problem.

Comment: are your tabs using ajax? What I mean by this is, does all the content get loaded on page load, or when you click the second tab, the content of the second tab is loaded with ajax?

Comment: I have selected the option in AJAX of Quicktabs of: "Yes: Load only the first tab on page view" . So yes, when I click the second tab the content is loaded with ajax.